# .NET Core package to generate and print PDF files

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdf-generation

I'm currently working on a proof of concept to generate and print a ticket on a thermal Bematech printer.

I'm using the HtmlRendererCore PdfSharp package to generate the PDF, using an HTML file as a template. The PDF is successfully generated, but it seems that the CSS is not being applied properly. Tags like Flex and others are not rendering as expected.

```
var document = new PdfSharpCore.Pdf.PdfDocument();

var today = DateTime.UtcNow;

TicketHeader header = new TicketHeader()
{
    Test= "some value",
    Test2= "Some value 2",
    ScheduledTime = DateTime.UtcNow
};

TicketContent content= new TicketContent
{
    Name = "Test"
    dsc= "Test2"

};

var htmlPage = System.IO.File.ReadAllText($"Models\\TicketLayout.html");

htmlPage = htmlPage.Replace("DAY", header.ScheduledTime.ToString());
htmlPage = htmlPage.Replace("Test", header.Test);
htmlPage = htmlPage.Replace("Test2", header.Test);

htmlPage = htmlPage.Replace("Name", detail.Name);
htmlPage = htmlPage.Replace("Dsc", detail.Dsc);

byte[]? result = null;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(htmlPage, PdfSharpCore.PageSize.A4);

    pdf.Save(stream);
    result = stream.ToArray();
}
string Filename = "Ticket_test".pdf";
return File(result, "application/pdf", Filename);
```

this is my HTML template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<style>
        .container {
            width: 300px;
        }

        .header-title {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .aling-left {
            display: flex;
            float: right;
        }

        .centered-info {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bolded {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <p class="header-title">
            <span>DAY</span>
            <span class="aling-left">HOUR</span>
        </p>

        <p class="centered-info">
            <span class="bolded">Test</span>
            <br>
            <span>Order</span>
            <br>
            <span class="bolded">Test</span>
        </p>

        <hr style="centered-info">

        <div>
            <span class="bolded">DUMMY DATA</span>
            <span style="margin-left: 10px">DUMMY DATA</span>

            <span style="font-weight: bold; margin-left: 10px">DUMMY DATA</span>
            <span style="margin-left: 10px">DUMMY DATA</span>

            <br>
            <span style="font-weight:bold;margin-right: 10px">DUMMY DATA</span>
            <span>DUMMY DATA</span>
            <span>|</span>
            <span>DUMMY DATA</span>
        </div>

        <div style="padding: 10px; border: solid; border-radius: 15px; margin-top: 20px">
            <span style="font-weight: bold">12345</span>
            <span style="">DUMMY DATA</span>

            <br>

            <span style="font-weight: bold; margin-right: 20px">DUMMY DATA</span>
            <span style="font-weight: bold; margin-right: 30px">DUMMY DATA.</span>
            <span style="font-weight: bold; margin-right: 30px">DUMMY DATA</span>

            <br>

            <span style="font-weight: bold;margin-right:35px;">DUMMY DATA</span>
            <span style="margin-right: 15px">DUMMY DATA</span>
            <span style="">DUMMY DATA</span>

            <br>

            <span style="font-weight: bold">DUMMY DATA.</span>

        </div>

        <span style="padding: 20px">Some text</span>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm wondering if there might be an issue with the HTML itself or if it's related to the package. Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and do you have any suggestions on how to address this issue?

Additionally, if there's a better package for this task that you could recommend, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i`ve already tried to use @media print in the style tag, didn`t work as well.

Comment: _"if there's a better package for this task that you could recommend"_ - while _asking_ for it is actually off-topic and I'll probably get under fire for it, but: Have you heard of [QuestPDF](https://www.questpdf.com/)? I haven't tried it (yet) myself but heard good things about it. So, if it helps you ...

Comment: yeah, i tried at first, but its not open source, so i`m tring to avoid those kind of packages.

I know i`m asking for to much, a package for being free and good haha :(

Comment: _"Tags like Flex and others are not rendering as expected."_ - Can you post an example? (In that case, an image is ok)

Comment: yeah.

This is the image of the HTML rendered:
https://ibb.co/N2vJ5hJ

and this is how the PDF is being generated:

https://ibb.co/WVWyc0z

Comment: Do you have documentation on what CSS is supported by the HtmlToPdf rendering? One of the obvious things seems to be the border-radius, ...

Comment: sorry for the delay.

I did'nt find any relevant information in the documentation of those packages related to that.

So i migrate my solution to generate the PDF file in the Angular side.